# Sqlglot Snowflake parsing issue

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqlglot

**Input Sql**

```
WITH first_activity AS (
  SELECT USER_ID, MIN(TO_TIMESTAMP(EVENT_DATE)) AS first_activity_date
  FROM DF.USER_EVENTS
  GROUP BY USER_ID
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS active_users_count
FROM first_activity
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, first_activity_date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) > 90
```

I am using sqlglot transpile function in the following manner
`sqlglot.transpile(query, write="snowflake", pretty=True)[0]`

**Output Query**

```
WITH first_activity AS (
  SELECT
    USER_ID,
    MIN(TO_TIMESTAMP(EVENT_DATE)) AS first_activity_date
  FROM DF.USER_EVENTS
  GROUP BY
    USER_ID
)
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS active_users_count
FROM first_activity
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(, first_activity_date, day) > 90
```

The output query is failing as there is a leading comma in the DATEDIFF function. Moreover I'm not sure why it changed the function signature and parameters altogether.

I was expecting the query to be the same with some prettiness.

Comment: DATEDIFF also accepts string for the time token, so you could try `DATEDIFF('day', first_activity_date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())` and then the constant string token might be handled more correctly.

Comment: I would explicitly set the read parameter, also possibly set the log level as high as possible